# flutter layout center single item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
----------------------------
          @ Text          *
----------------------------
```

- `Text` in the center
- `@` left of `Text` and it is variable length
- `*` at the far right and it is variable length

I've tried using `spaceBetween` but it doesn't seem to work because components width are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Expanded for @ in Container with alignment centerRight, Text, Expanded for * in Container with alignment centerRight in Row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Expanded widget to achieve this, Using Expanded Widget you can control the width or height of each child in Row or Column Widget

In Your case Use Row Widget with Expanded for each child

For Example:

```
Row(
children: [
  Expanded(
    flex: 2,
    child: Text("@")
  ),
  Expanded(
    flex: 2,
    child: Text("Text")
  ),
  Expanded(
    flex: 1,
    child: Text("*")
  ),
 ]
)
```

Adjust the value of **flex** value according to your needs and align text to left. right, or center

For more info check out this link and for video: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html